# c++ code won't run on Visual Studios due to errors but no errors are shown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have written a simple program to output different temperature units using conversions given. When I run the code on Visual Studios, it won't run due to build errors but no errors are shown. I have seen similar questions asked but couldn't really see any answer that solved my issue. I was also wondering whether I should be declaring the variables before or after the main function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fahrenheit, i=0;
float celsius, absolute_value;

main() {
    cout.width(20);
    cout << "Fahrenheit" << "Celsius" << "Absolute value\n";
    for (i = 0; i = 15; i += 1) {
        fahrenheit = i * 20;
        celsius = ((fahrenheit - 30) * 5) / 9;
        absolute_value = celsius + 273.15;
        cout.width(20); /*each item in next output will have width of at least 20*/
        cout << fahrenheit << celsius << absolute_value;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Visual Studios it won't run due to build errors but no errors are shown* That sentence does not make sense.

Comment: Do you get a build error, or do you get a run time exception?

Comment: What are the errors? You are missing the includes for iostream and the return value for the main function

Comment: `i = 15` is an assignment.

Comment: `main` is required to have the return type `int` in c++.

Comment: Include the return type for the main method to be `int main() {` and see what that does.

Comment: @RSahu I have added a comma to clarify

Comment: @NathanOliver I got the standard: "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build" message.

Comment: @jdog, that doesn't still clarify what you are seeing in your code. Is there a compile time error? Is there a link time error? Is there a run time error?

Comment: @jdog Did you look at the "Output" tab, or the "Error list"?

Comment: If you say no, down on the bottom, are there errors listed there in the build window?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have already included these

Comment: Switch the bottom pane from the Error List tab to the Output tab and see if the full build output gives you better diagnostics.

Comment: @RSahu "_That doesn't still clarify what you are seeing in your code._" This is the text, inside a message box, that you get, when you try to run the VS project, if such project has compilation/linking errors.

Comment: @Nordii that's worked thanks. Why do I need to include int with main?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks. that's happed helped as well.

Comment: @jdog 1) "_Why do I need to include int with main_" `main` is a function. Functions need to have return type. The return type of `main` is defined by the C++ standard. 2) Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of coding randomly.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Apologies. I now realise that was a stupid question. I had misread my example code.

Comment: Glad it worked. Posted explanation as an answer.

Comment: @user4581301 How do I do this?

Comment: [This question is completely unrelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125153/activate-visual-studios-output-window-using-dte) but contains a picture showing the location of the output tab.

Comment: @Nordii The only problem is now the formatting is wrong. It's not producing a table as expected.

Comment: My answer was to get your code to compile and run. The next step is getting the right outputs. If you got your `for` loop working, don't forget to use spaces and newlines to adjust the formatting of your temperatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Fahrenheit\t" << "Celsius\t\t" << "Absolute value\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) 
    {
        const int fahrenheit = i * 20;
        const float celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5) / 9;
        const float absolute_value = celsius + 273.15;
        std::cout << fahrenheit << "\t\t" << celsius << "\t\t"<< absolute_value << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Issues fixed:

- main must return `int`
- loop had assignement instead of comparison
- variables should not be global
- `using namespace std;` should be avoided
- formula for fahrenheit to celsius was wrong
- celsius was calculated with interger arithmetic despite being float
- `const` correctness
- cosmetic: formatted output with tabs

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are you able to give an answer using a for loop and cout.width() as this is how we were told to do it in the lecture notes. Why do use const with these variables? So am I right in thinking that if Celsius is a float I much use 32.0 and not 32?

Comment: the 32.0 ensures you actually get the float result for celsius.you can use the cout.width if you want, nothing wrong with that. const is used because the variables are not changed (they are newly created on every run of the loop)

Comment: also you might want to have a look at the [c++ book guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: with 32 instead of 32.0 the celsius will be calculated as int converted to float after calculation during assignment, the .0 ensures floating point arithmetic is used on calculation

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some coding errors. I think there are still some logical errors but now the code compile and program should run

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout.width(20);
    cout << "Fahrenheit" << "Celsius" << "Absolute value\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i += 1) {
        int fahrenheit = i * 20;
        float celsius = ((fahrenheit - 30) * 5) / 9;
        float absolute_value = celsius + 273.15;
        cout.width(20); /*each item in next output will have width of at least 20*/
        cout << fahrenheit << ' ' << celsius << ' ' << absolute_value << '\n';
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

You are missing the includes for iostream and the return type for the `main` function. I also moved the declaration of the global variables to where the variables are used the first time. The for loop was an endless loop. So I changed `i = 15` to `i <= 15`. Maybe you wanted a loop condition like `i < 15`. I also added whitespaces and linebreaks between the values.

Comment: Recommend marking and explaining the changes made. Are you sure you want `i <= 15` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @user4581301 _"Are you sure you want `i <= 15` in the `for` loop?"_ Doesn't do any harm IMO.

Comment: Please note that `cout.width(20);` only affects the *next* output, not "each item in next output". Also `fahrenheit` is an `int'...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not going to argue that. I worded the comment poorly poorly and should have recommended calling it out as a potential logic error. >= is an unusual thing to see in a `for` loop, and the unusual is usually a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `int` return type to the `main` signature.

In c++, the standard expects the `main` function to return an `int`, just as it expects the function to be called `main`. The return is most often used as an exit code, where `0` usually means successful execution without error.

Adding this in should allow your program to compile and run.